# LaTeX Template for Graduate School Essays

Tags: templates

I'm looking for a professional LaTeX template for either a statement or purpose/personal statement/statement of intent/etc. for a general graduate application. Most of the ones I have seen thus far have been relatively plain, and while I don't need a template that is horribly visually abrasive, one with a bit more style wouldn't be bad. Are there any good repositories for essays of this nature or does anybody from the community have a particularly well-crafted template of this type?

Comment: As the director of a graduate program I can say that the format of your personal/academic statement is unlikely to have much influence on the admissions process.  Focus on the content and why the program you're applying to is a good fit for your research interests, and make sure the prose is error free. Many universities have online applications so your statement may end up being plain unformatted text when it's read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a similar issue myself when looking for CV templates. I came across this site, which was quite helpful and the .tex files are easily modifiable as most of the examples at the bottom of the page are using the letter class.

http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/help/faqs/latex/letters

Comment: This link is returning a 404 now, but I've located what I think might be a similar page at the same site: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/letters